# Earth tilt changes due to space launches

Tags: science-based, orbital-mechanics, earth, geophysics

How many rocket launches are needed to change the axial tilt of the Earth so much that it is noticeable with instruments available today?

We can assume that we are talking about the heaviest rocket ever launched and that all launches are done from the same place, in the same season and at the same hour, all chosen for the biggest effect on the axial tilt.

(I know that the axial tilt is already changing due to natural reasons, my question regards an additional change attributable only to space launches)

Later edit: I'm looking for an answer that involves the kinetic energy derived from the mass and speed of the rocket at launch (and possibly later in the atmosphere). An explosion or an earthquake is usually not directed and much of the energy would be lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a planet's axial tilt be changed by carefully planned and set high-energy explosions?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96873/can-a-planets-axial-tilt-be-changed-by-carefully-planned-and-set-high-energy-ex)

Answer (score 4):

The earthquake of Tohoku in 2011 shifted the Earth axis by 10 cm. It had a magnitudo of 9.0, meaning it [released an energy](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_Richter) of about 2 EJ, or 477 MTon.

The Saturn V could release a [total energy](https://www.quora.com/How-do-the-Saturn-V-and-other-rockets-compare-with-various-nuclear-bombs-in-terms-of-power-force-and-energy) of about 5 kTon.

We see that to have a comparable release of energy we would need about 500 thousand Saturn V, assuming that the effect of each single launch can simply sum up without losses of any kind.

Comment: I think that only works if the launches are done in a very short time span. Earthquakes, and I think hurricanes and tidal bores as well, keep changing the tilt too - the effect of rockets would be lost among the effects of nature itself.

Comment: @Renan No, that's not how physics works. The total effect of 365 Saturns V launched simultaneously would be the same as one Saturn V each day for a year.

Comment: @MrLister if I lit one match per day under a frypan for an year it will receive the same amount of energy as if I had let it rest on a lit stove for a few minutes. One way gets the meal ready, the other one does not. I believe that's how physics work.

Comment: This is this is kind of besides the topic here, but I wonder why the Earth's axial tilt isn't completely askew given that the Earth has likely seen many such events throughout its history. Perhaps the randomness involved neutralizes those effects.

Comment: @B.fox: Because the Earth's spin absorbs most of the wobble, just like a bullet fired from a rifle

Comment: @Renan your analogy doesn't work.  Heat can be dissipated into the air.  Angular momentum is conserved.  Every launch that does not result in the rocket returning to Earth would change the Earth's tilt ever so slightly, and that change in momentum cannot just be dissipated into anywhere.  Earthquakes change the Earth's tilt the same way an ice skater spins faster by pulling their arms in - the total angular momentum is conserved.  However, rockets permanently leaving the Earth change the Earth's angular momentum permanently.

Comment: @Christyn earthquakes and other phenomena move the tilt in random directions. One single launch's influence gets lost among everything that influences the Earth's tilt. By the time you do the 500,000th Saturn V lanch, the tilt will have been moved by so many forces, the influence of all the launches will be imperceptible.

Comment: @Renan you missed my point.  All those random movements by earthquakes and other phenomena do not change the total angular momentum of the Earth at all.  They can't, because they are acting in what is essentially a closed system.  Rocket launches change the total angular momentum, and that tiny amount of change is categorically different than the change from an earthquake.

Comment: I am surprised the number of Saturn V launches to produce even a 10 cm change of tilt is so small. Your assumption about there being no losses of any kind is a wise one. A remarkably interesting result.