# Human caused disasters creating a whole new continent

Tags: geology, weapon-mass-destruction, natural-disasters

So my world needs to be destroyed because of a variety of things.
New land masses would be created and destroyed and joined till we had a single continent.

In the future, people saw the possibility of humans doing this, so scientists found particular areas that wouldn't be so affected by the 'end' and people would be relocated there in order to survive.

Everyone else would die. The community would be prepared and the people would survive and thrive. Technology would be limited; it would be a farming community. Several other communities will actually survive the end as well. Each would be successful in different ways due to the way the world was.

The huge Pangea like continent would have one large mountain range that splits in two in the center of the continent. There would be a couple of small islands near a peninsula. In the landlocked areas, there are underground water masses that only the main community utilizes. other than that there are fresh water rivers everywhere. There is a mix of plains and forests. but on one side of the mountains, there is mainly snow, then there are beaches and then forests and plains.

Could several human-caused disasters do this?

Comment: When typing long text, try using line breaks. They avoid the wall of text effect and make the post easier to read.

Comment: (Not like it would change the answer), but do you want this continent-forming event take a few years, or a few million years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Messing with magma accelerates plate tectonics.**

[image: magma!]

http://theconversation.com/magma-power-how-superheated-molten-rock-could-provide-renewable-energy-67725
Fracking is the injection of soapy water and other stuff to loosen up petrochemicals.  Fracking can precipitate earthquakes.  In your world, the molten core of the Earth is tapped for energy - lots and lots of energy that is used to do amazing things.  It turns out messing with magma had unexpected (but not unpredicted; see OP) effects on continental motion.  Plate tectonics accelerated in extremely destructive ways, changing the continents and essentially wiping out civilization everywhere except for your refuge.

Comment: Please note the refuge, as described in the question, is unlikely to survive the geological convulsions accompanying your proposed plate tectonic acceleration. The entire biosphere will be wiped out. All human civilization too.

Comment: "superheated magma"f

Answer (score 3):

I decided to change my comment into an answer.

**Scientifically, no, there is no series of human-geneated events using technology available to us today that could achieve what you're looking for.**

In my answer to [Can a planet's axial tilt be changed by carefully planned and set high-energy explosions?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96873/can-a-planets-axial-tilt-be-changed-by-carefully-planned-and-set-high-energy-ex/96919#96919) I compare the Magnitude 9 Sumatra Earthquake to the RDS-220 Tsar Bomba explosion.  It points out pretty clearly that the energy humanity needed to tilt the earth a few centimeters would destroy more than half the planet.

Humanity simply doesn't have the ability to change much of anything on a planetary basis without a considerable period of time.

**But this isn't important!**

However, scientifically accurate is irrelevant, isn't it? The movie *[The Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Core)* uses a fictional how-to-make-an-earthquake experiment to cause the core to stop spinning, thereby setting up the premise for the story.

This is important.  Stopping the core from spinning was simply *backstory.*  It's not really that important and not particularly explained in the movie.  This is because how the core was stopped *isn't actually the story the writers wanted to tell.*  It was simply the premise to set up the story they really wanted to tell.

**So, what you're really looking for are explanations that allow readers to suspend their disbelief just long enough to get to the story you really want to tell.**

- The tiny middle-eastern country of Bahrain has had it up to here with all the nuclear super powers!  They want to be a nuclear super power, too!  So they steal nuclear bomb tech from Iran, Pakistan, and India, and resolve to set off *the biggest underground nuclear test in history!*  They're not fools!  Nosiree!  They're going to set off their 1,000 megaton nuke an astonishing 1,500 miles below the surface!  That's almost the bottom of the mantle!  After all, they don't actually want to hurt anybody.  They just want respect!  And on the day they decided to push the button — the Earth reacted with what can only be called *indigestion.*
- Greenland is tired of waiting for the world to solve global warming.  It wants its glaciers back!  Exhausted of patience, they contracted with the Chinese to send a series of boosters into space ostensibly to set some high-orbit satellites.  But they hijacked the boosters!  They found this rogue asteroid that looks like it's all ice and they're determined to land that sucker right on top of Greenland.  Glaciers forever!  Unfortunately, they didn't realize the reflective surface of the asteroid was actually *mercury,* and the much more massive than expected asteroid slammed into the Earth taking Greenland and most of Northern America, Europe, and northern Asia with it.  On the other side of the Earth, landmasses connecting South America, Africa, and Australia popped up due to the concussion wave of the impact.
- Nobody paid much attention to the *Atlantis Arrives!* blog until intelligence agencies world-wide started tracking explosive shipments arriving all around the Pacific's Rim of Fire.  I mean, it's Atlantis, *right?*  What could those nut jobs possiblly do?  Unbeknownst to the world's intelligence agencies (something that's apparently much easier to do than anybody thought), several mega corps have been convinced that Atlantis really is in the middle of the Atlantic ocean (Atlantis... Atlantic... can't be a coincidence... *right?*)  As usual, the intelligence agencies received confirmation via CNN when the explosives blew, raising the Atlantic sea floor and sinking Australia and most of the land surrounding the Indian Ocean....

**Have some fun with this.  People will swallow almost any ridiculous premise if the story you really want to tell is worth telling.  Every "Young Adult" book on earth lives by this axiom.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88555/discussion-on-answer-by-jbh-human-caused-disasters-creating-a-whole-new-continen).